# Initialize array of pointers to NULL

Tags: c++, c, arrays

here's to my first post on this website.

I'm trying to initialize an array of 30 pointers to NULL. The array is stored as a global and I'm doing the initialization in my init() function like so:

---

`static headerT* free_list[30];`

....

`init() {
    free_list[30] = {NULL};
}`

---

However, I get the following complier error - "error: expected expression before ‘{’ token".

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're already initialized.

Comment: Just delete the `init()` function.

Comment: the element `free_list[30]` does not exist: the array goes from `free_list[0]` to `free_list[29]`

Comment: In [tag:c]? Or [tag:c++]?

Answer (score 3):

objects allocated with static storage duration are value initialized.  Your pointers are already initialized to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

1. If `arr` is an array of n elements, then the first cell is `arr[0]` and the last is `arr[29]`. `arr[30]` is outside the array and referencing it can cause all sorts of problems.
2. You can't assign a value to an entire array. Use a `for` loop to access every cell.

Thus we get:

```
init() 
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<30; i++)
        free_list[i] = NULL; 
}
```

Comment: To be clear, only pointers with static storage duration are initialized to `NULL` by default.

Comment: You can also initialise a (non-static) array of pointers to NULL (0) by writing `T* p[30] = { 0 };`, but you can't assign such a value.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer memset

memset( free_list, 0x0, 30 * sizeof(headerT*) );

Comment: This will break on a system where the null pointer is not represented by all-bits-zero.

Comment: Also it will break if the size of the list changes, you could at least have used the idiom `memset( &x, 0, sizeof x )` to ensure the correct amount of memory is written.

Comment: Yes I could have but the example that was given was fairly specific and I had no problem with giving a specific answer.  The specific version of this function that i coded up for myself is templated but i thought that was overkill for the question.